# In Django, where is the correct place to put a base.html that includes CDN links used by all apps?

Tags: html, django

When you start a Django project called "myproject", within that project you get a folder also called "myproject". Should I put my base.html (which includes links to CDNs like Bootstrap that are used by all my apps) in a folder called "myproject" within a templates folder within the "myproject" folder? In other words, should I put the base.html in myproject/templates/myproject and then place at the top of each HTML page in every app:

`{% extends 'myproject/templates/myproject/base.html %}`?

Alternatively, do I place a base.html in each app and extend like:
 `{% extends 'myapp/templates/myapp/base.html %}`? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep your base.html in `myapp/templates/base.html`

and you can extend it using,

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}  on each HTML template..
```

but  ensure your TEMPLATE_DIRS in `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
        ],
        .....
    }
]
```

django will take of template dir path automatically...

Comment: Thank you. So this means I will have a base.html file in every app within my project, correct?

Comment: no you will have base.html in one location but it will reference (extend code into many wherever you defined ) like external css defined one place but we can use it as much as possible by id/name...